# Given a value of some path-dependent type, how can I get an instance of the "container"?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

It's more easily explained in code:

```
class Bippy {
  val x = 42

  class Boppy {
    val y = "hello world"
  }

  val bop = new Boppy
}

val bip = new Bippy
val bop: Bippy#Boppy = bip.bop
```

`bop` is then supplied to another method, which needs to find the value `x` from the containing instance of `Bippy`.  What's the magic incantation to do so?

The instance `bop` comes from code that I don't control, so adding new methods to `Boppy` isn't an option here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  At least not without cheating.  Here's how to cheat.

```
def getOuter(bop : Bippy#Boppy) = 
   bop.asInstanceOf[{def Bippy$Boppy$$$outer() : Bippy}].Bippy$Boppy$$$outer()
```

Obviously that's very dependent on details of how scalac works today and no guarantees that it will work tomorrow.

Comment: It's the solution I'm using already :)  But as it seems there's no better way, you get the green tick, bleeding eyes and all!

Answer (score 4):

As James said, you can't. His cheat makes my eyes bleed, and I suggest doing something else instead ;-)

I strongly recommend modifying the consumers of bop if you can. Rather than handing them an instance of Bippy#Boppy, hand them a pair comprising the value of the dependent type and the value that the type depends on,

```
trait DependentPack {
  val bippy : Bippy
  val boppy : bippy.Boppy
}

val bip = new Bippy
val bop = bip.bop
val dep = new DependentPack { val bippy = bip ; val boppy = bop }
foo(dep)

def foo(dp : DependentPack) = {
  import dp._
  // use bippy ...
  // use boppy ...
}
```

Note that this is in part a workaround for the lack of dependent method types (enabled in scalac by adding the -Ydependent-method-types or -Xexperimental command line switches). If we had them, then we could drop artefacts like DependentPack and rewrite the above as,

```
val bip = new Bippy
val bop = bip.bop
foo(bip)(bop)

def foo(bippy : Bippy)(boppy : bippy.Boppy) = {
  // use bippy ...
  // use boppy ...
}
```

Needless to say, I think having dependent method types enabled by default would be highly desirable. Non-trivial uses of dependent types bring a world of pain with them in their absence unless you're very careful.

Comment: I guess I took his problem as "I have a Boppy that came from somewhere else and I need to get its Bippy".  If something like Miles' solution is possible then by all means do this.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have access to `bip` either.  Just `bop` and an unruly type signature...

Comment: Still, good call on the dependent typing! It deserves to get a bit of an airing out from time to time.